# Entity Framework Core - More than one Discriminator for derived classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have a model that is structurd as follows (fields ommited for brevity):

```
public enum ActivityType { Production, Downtime } 
public enum ActivityStatus { Planned Actual }

public abstract class Activity
{
    public virtual ActivityType ActivityType {get;}
    public virtual ActivityStatus ActivityStatus {get;}
}

public abstract class PlannedActivity : Activity
{
    public override ActivityStatus ActivityStatus => ActivityStatus.Planned;
}

public abstract class ActualActivity : Activity
{
    public override ActivityStatus ActivityStatus => ActivityStatus.Actual;
}
```

Then the concrete 'Entity' classes

```
public class PlannedDowntime : PlannedActivity
{
    public override ActivityType ActivityType => ActivityType.Downtime;
}
public class PlannedProduction : PlannedActivity
{
    public override ActivityType ActivityType => ActivityType.Production;
}
public class ActualDowntime : ActualActivity
{
    public override ActivityType ActivityType => ActivityType.Downtime;
}
public class ActualProduction : ActualActivity
{
    public override ActivityType ActivityType => ActivityType.Production;
}
```

I'm trying to save all data to a single database table (i.e. TPH).

In EF6, the following code achieves the database and model structure that I'm looking for:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>()
    .Map<PlannedProductionActivity>(m =>
    {
        m.Requires("ActivityType").HasValue("Production");
        m.Requires("ActivityStatus").HasValue("Planned");
    })
    .Map<PlannedDowntimeActivity>(m =>
    {
        m.Requires("ActivityType").HasValue("Downtime");
        m.Requires("ActivityStatus").HasValue("Planned");
    })
    .Map<ActualProductionActivity>(m =>
    {
        m.Requires("ActivityType").HasValue("Production");
        m.Requires("ActivityStatus").HasValue("Actual");
    })
    .Map<ActualDowntimeActivity>(m =>
    {
        m.Requires("ActivityType").HasValue("Downtime");
        m.Requires("ActivityStatus").HasValue("Actual");
    });
```

But...I need to move this over to EF Core (2.1), and I'm struggling. The following code is the closest I can get, but when migrating it fails with the error 'Every concrete entity type in the hierarchy needs to have a unique discriminator value.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>()
    .HasDiscriminator<ActivityStatus>("ActivityStatus")
    .HasValue<PlannedActivity>(ActivityStatus.Planned)
    .HasValue<ActualActivity>(ActivityStatus.Actual);

modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>()
    .HasDiscriminator<ActivityType>("ActivityType")
    .HasValue<PlannedDowntimeActivity>(ActivityType.Downtime)
    .HasValue<ActualDowntimeActivity>(ActivityType.Downtime)
    .HasValue<PlannedProductionActivity>(ActivityType.Production)
    .HasValue<ActualProductionActivity>(ActivityType.Production);
```

Please can anyone cast some light on how to have more than one discriminator?

Comment: You have 4 entities but only 2 sections in the model builder, is that exactly what you had?

Comment: Yes, this all the code. The two sections are for each discriminator 'ActivityStatus' and 'ActivityType'

Answer (score 3):

Well, seems a little odd to need two discriminators -

but you could structure it so that Activity has a discriminator and then the sub classes also have their own discriminators

alternatively make a complex discriminator

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>()
.HasDiscriminator(x=> new {x.ActivityStatus, x.ActivityType})
.HasValue<PlannedDowntimeActivity>(new {ActivityStatus.Planned,ActivityType.Downtime} );
```

along the lines of above - but with extra values, have a bunch of ones like above throughout our own code base now

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I gave this some thought overnight. I'm unable to move a discriminator to a subclass, on migration this gives the error:    A discriminator property cannot be set for the entity type 'ActualActivity' because it is not the root of an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: The complex discriminator gives the error:   CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: Model.ActivityStatus Planned,Model.ActivityType Downtime>' to '<anonymous type: Model.ActivityStatus ActivityStatus, Model.ActivityType ActivityType>'